# Search for substring in string using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How can I extract the currency1 field in the following string:

```
<fxQuotation><currency1>USD</currency1><currency2>AUD</currency2>
```

The result should be USD.

The below command would work:

```
echo "<fxQuotation><currency1>USD</currency1><currency2>AUD</currency2>" | cut -d">" -f3 | cut -d"<" -f1
```

However what if that string was a substring in a very big xml file, then my command would not work. How can I search based on the currency1 field.

Comment: Any reason in particular why you're not just using an XML parser?

Comment: because the file is not pure xml(half text, half xml), i tried to parse it in java, but this resulted in errors

Comment: It seems to me that asking a question about those Java errors makes more sense? At any rate, tools like `cut` should work reasonably well even for (very) large files. How exactly are you invoking it? Probably not with `echo` like in the question?

Comment: I followed http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm. The file they use is pure xml, with one root element. My file is different in that it is a log file, with xml as log messages. So it has mutiple xml messages. I can extract the xml part and write it to a file, but I would have to do it for all xml messages, will have multiple files to analyse, and this is time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a xml parser or xml querying language instead of regex and bash commands.

For Java see `DOM`,`SAX`,`StAX` etc based xml parsers. `DOM` loads all of your xml as a tree representation in memory, so it's fast but memory inefficient; on the other hand `SAX` and `StAX` are much more better as they handle `xml` in pull or push fashion firing events. So you just have to write event handlers for their events.
`WoodStox` library is a good, efficient and sort of configurable xml parser. More info: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html
http://www.studytrails.com/java/xml/woodstox/java-xml-stax-woodstox-basic-parsing.jsp

You can also use SQL like syntax for xml by using XQuery; another language to get your data can be xpath.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xquery_intro.asp

But if you still insist using bash tools.. just grep your string with `-o` option to get your desired tag along with its content(`-o` returns only strings which match regex line by line) and then remove the tags using `cut` or `sed` or any other tool:

```
$ cat file1
text text abcd
cxyz
xyz

</rootelement>
<abcd>
<xyz><fxQuotation><currency1>USD</currency1><currency2>AUD</currency2></fxQuotation></xyz>
</abcd>
</rootelement>
$ egrep -o '<currency1>[^<]*</currency1>' file1
<currency1>USD</currency1>
$ egrep -o '<currency1>[^<]*</currency1>' file1 | sed -r 's/<[^>]*>//g'
USD
$ grep -oP '(?<=<currency1>)[^<]*(?=</currency1>)' file1
USD
$
```

Comment: `sed` can be avoided if you use `grep -oP '(?<=<currency1>).*?(?=<\/currency1>)'` to match the tags as lookbehind and lookahead.

Answer (score 2):

Very easy using [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel file.xml --extract "//currency1" -q
```

or

```
xidel file.xml --xpath "//currency1" -q
```

The two work with badly formatted XML/HTML/XML with text...

Answer (score 1):

You would be best off using a small custom program in C or Python, but 'awk' and 'sed' are old tools that may offer a simple solution in a shell script:
see [Print XML element with AWK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682503/print-xml-element-with-awk) 
but the big thing is ensuring your input is pristine and well-formed.